# Checking account - Problem with withdrawing with overdraft

Tags: java, object

I'm having trouble with a Java OOP exercise. The program uses two classes, the object class Account and the Main class to print whatever the user wants.

It's a standard checkings account with an overdraft limit, the issue I'm having is printing out the account balance if the user decides to withdraw more than the account balance, I can't seem to get the overdraft logic down, can anyone help me out?

#### Account classs

```
public boolean withdraw(double amount) {
    balance = this.getBalance() + overDraftLimit;
    
    if ((balance - amount) >= 0) {
        this.setBalance(this.getBalance() - amount);
        balance -= amount;
        return true;
    } else if ((balance - amount) <= 0) {
        System.out.println("The amount you wish to withdraw is more than your balance -> Using overdraft to complete your transaction!");
        this.setBalance((this.getBalance() - amount) + overDraftLimit);
        return true;
    }
        return false;
} // ***** WITHDRAW *****

// ***** toString *****

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account numer: " + accountNumber + "\nYour current balance is: $" + balance + "\nYour overdraft limit is: $" + overDraftLimit;
    }
```

}

```
### Main class

        Account ac1 = new Account();
        
        ac1.setAccountNumber(1234);
        ac1.setOverDraftLimit(50);
        
        System.out.println(ac1);
        
        System.out.println("\nSucessful deposit");
        ac1.deposit(100);
        
        System.out.println("Your current balance is: $" + ac1.getBalance());
                
        makeWithdraw(ac1, 50);
        makeWithdraw(ac1, 50);
        makeWithdraw(ac1, 25);

    }

    public static void makeWithdraw (Account ac1, double amount) {
        if (ac1.withdraw(amount)) {
            System.out.println("Withdraw was sucessful! Your new balance is: $" + ac1.getBalance());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Insufficient funds! Cannot withdraw " + amount + "Your current balance is: $"  + ac1.getBalance());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would recommend taking a look at how to produce a [mre] for your problem and make sure you include details of what you're expecting to happen, what's going wrong, what's causing it to go wrong etc.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score -1):

This will be the proper logic to handle the overdraft during withdrawl.

```
public boolean withdraw(double amount) {
    if(balance < -overDraftLimit) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((balance - amount) >= -overDraftLimit) {
        this.setBalance(this.getBalance() - amount);
        balance -= amount;
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
} // ***** WITHDRAW *****
```

**[EDIT]**

Here is an running example

```
public class Test{

public static class A {
    private int balance = 20;
    private int overDraftLimit = 50;
    public boolean withdraw(double amount) {
        if(balance < -overDraftLimit) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((balance - amount) >= -overDraftLimit) {
            balance -= amount;
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
    
    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}

 public static void main(String []args){
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(a.getBalance());
    System.out.println(a.withdraw(30));
    System.out.println(a.getBalance());
    System.out.println(a.withdraw(40));
    System.out.println(a.getBalance());
    System.out.println(a.withdraw(1));
    System.out.println(a.getBalance());
 }
}
```

Output:

```
20
true
-10
true
-50
false
-50
```